# heaviside function procudes different outputs in ezplot and fplot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm new to MATLAB and I'm trying to plot a step function with `heaviside()`. I tried at first the following code:

```
f = @(x)heaviside(x+2) - heaviside(x-2);
fplot(f, [-10 10])
```

The result:

[image]

With `ezplot`, the result is as I thought:

```
f = @(x)heaviside(x+2) - heaviside(x-2);
ezplot(f, [-10 10])
```

The result:

[image]

What is the difference between `fplot` and `ezplot`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pertains to the following bit of `fplot` documentation:

> `fplot` uses adaptive step control to produce a representative graph, concentrating its evaluation in regions where the function's rate of change is the greatest.

It sees that your function is constant just about everywhere and doesn't evaluate between `[-2 2]`. The solution is to specify a minimum number of evaluation points:

```
n = 1e3;
fplot(f, [-10 10],n)
```

For example, if we get the output coordinates from `fplot`:

```
>> [x,y] = fplot(f, [-10 10]);
>> [x y]

ans =

  -10.0000         0
   -9.9600         0
   -9.8800         0
   -9.7200         0
   -9.4000         0
   -8.7600         0
   -7.4800         0
   -4.9200         0
   -2.3600         0
    2.7600         0
   10.0000         0
```

You can see the adaptive evaluation in action. It starts at -10, steps forward faster and faster until it skips right from -2.36 to +2.76!  Seen on datatips:

[image]

If we use `n=1e3` evaluation points:

[image]

Comment: @LuisMendo Good point. Interesting to not though is that with `n=5`, it still ends up using 31 evaluation points. That really is the _minimum_ number you input... it reserves the right to use more.