# 2 different outputs when trying to fplot function

Tags: matlab, plot

trying to understand how matlab plot functions (fplot/ezplot) works.

dont understand why different outputs.

in the original example I see a dashed line on the x=2 (none here) where there is no value.

any help on printing the "right" version via fplot?

I noticed in the matlab help they point you not to use ezplot but fplot

none of the references helped a lot :(

```
syms x
fx = (x+2)/(x^2 - 4);
ht = matlabFunction(fx);

figure(1), clf

fplot(ht,[0 10])     % wrong plot
title('using fplot');

%ezplot(ht,[0 10])   % prints ok
%title('using ezplot');
```

[image: using ezplot]

[image]

references:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/32820-trouble-substituting-a-value-into-a-symbolic-expression-for-use-with-fplot
[heaviside function procudes different outputs in ezplot and fplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542814/heaviside-function-procudes-different-outputs-in-ezplot-and-fplot)

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I am using R2015b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using MATLAB R2017a.

When I run this code:

```matlab
f = @(x) (x+2)./(x.^2 - 4);
fplot(f,[0 10])
```

I see the following plot:

[image: correct plot]

I'm not using symbolic math above. I directly define an anonymous function that does numeric computation. I'm using `./` and `.^`, the element-wise operators, because `fplot` evaluates the function at many locations at the same time, by passing in `x` as an array, as described in [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html#bu6xntj-1-f):

> The function must accept a vector input argument and return a vector output argument of the same size.

Note that OP's code with `matlabFunction` should produce an equivalent function, I don't know what might be wrong there. But in general, avoiding symbolic math when it is not necessary is always beneficial. (By "necessary" I mean if, for example, you are trying to find an analytical solution to an equation.)

PS: In MATLAB R2021a I ran this code and OP's code, and obtained the exact same result. The `ht` from OP's code, and the `f` from my code are identical. It is possible that there was a bug in a specific version of MATLAB that has been fixed in a later version.

Comment: ya, running your code gives me the wrong figure :(

Comment: @mvcorrea Looks to be a bug in R2015b that has been fixed since. Could you try `fplot(f,[0 10],'MeshDensity',1e3)`?

Comment: upgraded and now everything works fine, thanks all